# How to collect different items in List box

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, windows-phone-7, xaml

I have a problem in my project. I have added ListBox and inside that I've added some TextBlock within that ListBox. Now I want to increase the number of ListBox dynamically as per requirement. I don't want to add ListBox each time from my self, it should increase automatically by coding.

Comment: I would suggest doing some research on how to add ListBox Items in Windows Phone..

Comment: you should add you code to the question and state [What have you tried?!](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: @DJKRAZE -but I think in that case data will be stored statically and also we can't increase the number of ListBox as per reuirement. I don't want to fix the size(no.) of the ListBox. If I'm wrong please tell me.

Comment: I have no Idea what your response means you may want to update your question because I am not be understanding what it is you are looking for..

Comment: @makc - I just added the ListBox and inside that added some TextBlock. But now I want to increase the number of ListBox dynamically. I don't want to add ListBox each time from myself, it should be automatically.

Comment: @DJKRAZE - Sorry for my poor english but please read the above comment. I think it will make you understand.

Comment: @user1928849 just a guess to what you really want, you should create an ObservableCollection and bind the listBox to it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

see the links here

[Grouping ListView items dynamically](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/853a6a/grouping-listview-items-dynamically/) and
[Using the ListView Widget](http://www.mosync.com/documentation/manualpages/using-listview-widget)

hope this will help u